# Как определить id клиента в gwt приложении?

Tags: java, mysql, веб-программирование, cookie, gwt

Есть *GWT* проект, лежащий на *Tomcat-сервере*.

В приложении пользователи могут нажать кнопку *получить баланс и изменить его* - данные приходят и отправляются на сервер, где происходит работа с базой данной. Все работает.

Но я в самом клиентском коде написал значение `id = 1`, и получается абсолютно все, кто заходит на сервер приложения, работают с одним и тем же балансом, с одной и той же строчкой в базе данных.
Форма авторизации не предусмотрена. *Http* протокол я не использую, у нас же в *gwt* асинхронные запросы на сервер.

Как мне определять `id` и задавать его конкретно под каждого пользователя?

Я читал про *Cookie*, но не знаю, то ли это. Там есть какой-то метод `Cookies.getCookie("JSESSIONID"));`. Скажите, это то, что надо?

Если да, то что это за значения `jsessionid`, ведь там совсем не цифры?

Если совсем не то, то какие есть еще способы назначать `id` для каждого клиента, и чтоб он не менялся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается примерно так:

1. Клиент подключается к серверу;
2. Сервер генерирует уникальный идентификатор и запоминает его и передает клиенту;
3. Клиент в каждом последующем запросе передает этот идентификатор а сервер 
   определяет что это за клиент уже по этому идентификатору.

Comment: Это все понятно, вопрос в том, как я сделаю, чтоб клиент запомнил идентификатор? Я перезапущу страницу в браузере, и начнется новая загрузка приложения - куда клиентская часть сохранит id, который до этого прислал сервер, сгенерировав и отослав? Расскажите, что вы имели ввиду подробнее, какие методы и где использовать.

Comment: Если у вас есть html5 - localstorage, если нет то cookies, А вообще если сессия поменялась - то и клиент считается другой.

Comment: Если ответ помог, пожалуйста отмечайте его как правильный, нажатием галочки слева, =)

Comment: Пока не знаю, еще не смотрел =) Но отмечу, хоть какая то наводка - лучше чем ничего. Спасибо.